# Plumber upload file csv in R

Tags: r, upload, swagger, plumber

I'd like upload file csv in plumber, but I see that take name of file and not path + name file for read my csv. How can I do read file in csv in the function?

> api_main.R
> #* @param file:file to send
> #* @post /sendFile function(file) {    read.csv(file) }
>
> plumber::plumb("api_main.R")$run(port = 5762)